# Boost.Python converting python tuple to `std::tuple` or to `std::pair`

Tags: boost-python

I'm trying to wrap class `Cube` with Boost.Python which has signature of the following form:

```
void insert( const std::pair< int, int>& x){ ... do something .. }
```

if I just wrap this method up as follows:

```
.def("append", &Cube::insert, with_custodian_and_ward<1,2>())
```

I get the following error in python:

```
ArgumentError: Python argument types in
    cube.append(cube, list)
 did not match C++ signature:
     append(Cube {lvalue}, std::__1::pair<unsigned long, unsigned long>)
```

when I type:

```
cube.append((1,2))
```

I'm not sure how to conver the python type to the c++ type correctly. I can't seem to find a suitable example either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest way would be to explicitly convert your python object into a c++ std::pair:

```
.def("append", FunctionPointer([] (Cube& self, const bp::object& obj)
  {
    self.insert(std::make_pair(bp::extract<int>(obj[0]),bp::extract<int>(obj[1])));
  }))
```